How do I read UEFI firmware data from a chip?
I need to implement a program running outside the operating system on the same level as the BIOS, which will read all the UEFI firmware data from the BIOS chip, which memory addresses need to be read (is there some kind of API to get all the UEFI firmware data?) and where exactly is the UEFI firmware?

Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Are you asking us to provide such a tool? If you are writing it, are you asking about what API you can use to get the info? What is this "ring 2" thing running?

This question is similar to: How to read UEFI firmware data from the LINUX kernel?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is not possible to read all UEFI firmware data from the chip from the operating system kernel. therefore, it is necessary to implement a program to read the UEFI firmware at a level higher than the operating system, in this case, working with memory is different from working with memory in the operating system. the problem is how to implement it, where to read the data from, are there ready-made firmware data reading functions and is it possible to read all the data?

Writing a UEFI program won’t help you work around the limitations of flashrom wrt to ME-protected parts of the ROM. The ME is set up before UEFI programs get a chance to run; the only workaround is either to disable ME protection if your firmware supports that, or to use external hardware.

In that case, how do I get around these restrictions? will implementing software at a higher level than UEFI help?

Before edit, you mentioned "ring -2", which suggests you are trying to access System Management Mode. You will essentially be programming on the bare hardware. You will have to do some light reading: start with the datasheets of your processor and system chipset. For debugging, you would need a logic analyzer connected to the system bus. Familiarity with assembler programming will also be a needed skill.

Note too that most of the restrictions involving SMM affect writing to flash, not reading from it. I was under the impression you’re interested in reading, not writing.

Exactly, I need to read the firmware data.

If you’ve tried flashrom, and it didn’t work, could you mention that in your question?

I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about Unix or Linux and should be asked on [su]

In this question, everything is actually explained. Without specialized hardware, it is not possible to read all UEFI firmware data directly from the chip.
How to read UEFI firmware data from the LINUX kernel?
While UEFI firmware data is stored in SPI flash memory on the motherboard, reading it at a low level outside the operating system requires specialized hardware (such as an SPI programmer) or access through an appropriate interface on the motherboard.
Within the operating system, firmware tools can retrieve certain information, but a complete dump of the firmware typically requires physical access or specific firmware debugging interfaces.
Normally, it is not possible to access the full UEFI firmware data on the chip with software alone, as this data is stored in a special flash memory on the motherboard. Accessing this memory often requires special interfaces or privileged firmware tools.
Some UEFI data, can be accessed through specific software APIs and system utilities (such as efivar or fwupd on Linux) within the operating system.
These mostly provide only environment variables and configuration data for UEFI, not the complete firmware data.
A complete dump of the firmware generally requires access to the SPI flash memory, for which specialized hardware is necessary.

There is no generic way an OS can access the system BIOS. This would only be possible if manufacturers were to provide detailed information and there were established standards as to how this is to be done. This is not the case, and I don't think it would be a good idea anyway.


There are security implications with this. If legitimate software could access the BIOS then there would be nothing to stop malicious software from doing the same.

How to read/write all BIOS settings from Linux CLI?
It is usually not possible to access the entire UEFI firmware data on the chip directly with software alone, as this data is stored in a special flash memory on the motherboard. Accessing this memory often requires special interfaces or privileged firmware tools.
Some UEFI data can be read through specific software APIs and system utilities (such as efivar, fwupd or other tools in Linux) within the running operating system.
These typically provide only environment variables and configuration data for UEFI, not the complete firmware data. A complete image of the firmware generally requires access to the SPI flash memory, which necessitates specialized hardware.
You need the exact specifications of the hardware and the chips from each manufacturer.
With newer devices, this would be a significant vulnerability, such as hacking the BIOS password or having malicious software install itself automatically if that were possible.
From your comments, I know that you want to pull the entire dump to generate a hash so that the system can later check whether malware or your BIOS/UEFI has changed, there is a lot of theory mixed with practice here!
Coreboot
Coreboot is an open-source firmware that serves as a replacement for proprietary BIOS/UEFI on x86 and ARM systems. It initializes the hardware, starts the operating system kernel, and can be combined with various payloads ( Linuxboot, SeaBIOS, or Tianocore) due to its modular design to provide functions that are typically integrated into BIOS/UEFI.
Coreboot allows for low-level control and modification of firmware, making it  useful for developers who need more control over the system.
It can be more secure and faster, as it only executes the functions necessary for the boot process.
Support for different motherboards is limited, as Coreboot requires customization for each specific hardware setup.
That is a possibility to potentially do something, but you should always keep security in mind, opening a door with just software could also allow malware to take advantage !
